# Show X input according to a variable

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to display X input according to a Prestashop configuration variable.

```
Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKPAYMENT_NB', 3);
```

Depending on the value entered it will display the X fields.

How is it possible to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: WIth a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you I find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKPAYMENT_NB', 3);
        $nbPayment = (int)Configuration::get('BLOCKPAYMENT_NB');

        for ($i = 0;$i < $nbPayment; $i++) {
            Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKPAYMENT_NB_'.$i, 30);
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.